# Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable when accessing available var

Tags: javascript, websocket, local-storage

I'm writing a client that communicates with a websocket server. Currently, the socket server sends a generated "token" to the client, which then sets it in storage with:

```
      localStorage.setItem('token', json.token);
```

And redirects to the next page, which on load, runs this code:

```
token = localStorage.getItem('token')


console.log(token)



socket.send(JSON.stringify({"type": "getplayerinfo", "token": token}));
```

When doing console.log(token), I get the token. However, when sending the token through the socket, I get:

```
Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

I've been debugging this for 3 days and have wracked my brain. Any tips?

Answer (score 8):

This normally happens when you try to send something through a websocket connection before the connection has fully connected to the server. So what you should do is run the code when the server sends a connected signal which you can using the event listener "open". In your case this would be:

```js
const socket = new Websocket(url);
socket.addEventListener("open", (ev) => {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify({"type": "getplayerinfo", "token": token}));
  });
```